# Hamburger Button Issue In WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am editing my website with elementor pro and oceanwp theme and  added a nav menu widget. It looks and work fine with the desktop and tab mode but when I open it in mobile mode a hamburger icon comes and when I click on this icon the drop down menu is not appearing.

I google this issue a lot but don't get any understandable explanation or any fix for this. Plz plz tell me how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you using caching plugin such as Autoptimize, WP Rocket, etc? If so, you can exclude js that responsible to handle menu's movement in your caching plugin. I am using Astra theme and WP rocket. You can view my setting here https://prnt.sc/13721rx